# how to read latitude and longitude in firebase to display in google maps android

Tags: android, firebase, maps

i want to retrieve latitude and longitude in firebase to display in maps.. i search some tutorial but it still eror, please help

it is code to upload in firebase(succes)

```
private Button mButtonChooseImage;
private Button mButtonUpload;
private Button mButtonLihatPeta;
private EditText edtName, edtDescription, edtLatitude, edtLongitude;
private ImageView mImageView;
private ProgressBar mProgressBar;

private Uri mImageUri;

private StorageReference mStorageRef;
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;

private StorageTask mUploadTask;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_firebase_tambah);

    mButtonChooseImage = findViewById(R.id.btn_choose_image);
    mButtonUpload = findViewById(R.id.btn_tambah_tower);
    mButtonLihatPeta = findViewById(R.id.btn_lihat_peta_tower);
    edtName = findViewById(R.id.editTextNamaTower);
    edtDescription = findViewById(R.id.editTextDeskripsi);
    edtLatitude = findViewById(R.id.editTextLatitude);
    edtLongitude = findViewById(R.id.editLongitude);
    mImageView = findViewById(R.id.image_viewtower);
    mProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

    mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("uploads");
    mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads");

    mButtonChooseImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openFileChooser();
        }
    });

    mButtonUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mUploadTask != null && mUploadTask.isInProgress()) {
                Toast.makeText(FirebaseTambah.this, "Upload Dalam Proses", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                uploadFile();
            }
        }
    });
        mButtonLihatPeta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(FirebaseTambah.this,MapsActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

}

private void openFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK
            && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        mImageUri = data.getData();

        Picasso.with(this).load(mImageUri).into(mImageView);
    }
}

private String getFileExtension(Uri uri) {
    ContentResolver cR = getContentResolver();
    MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
    return mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(cR.getType(uri));
}

private void uploadFile() {
    if (mImageUri != null) {
        final StorageReference fileReference = mStorageRef.child(System.currentTimeMillis()
                + "." + getFileExtension(mImageUri));

        mUploadTask = fileReference.putFile(mImageUri)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        Handler handler = new Handler();
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                mProgressBar.setProgress(0);
                            }
                        }, 500);

                        fileReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                Upload upload = new Upload(edtName.getText().toString().trim(), uri.toString(),edtDescription.getText().toString().trim(),edtLatitude.getText().toString().trim(),edtLongitude.getText().toString().trim());
                                String uploadID = mDatabaseRef.push().getKey();
                                mDatabaseRef.child(uploadID).setValue(upload);
                                Toast.makeText(FirebaseTambah.this, "Upload Berhasil", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagepreview);
                                edtName.setText("");
                                edtDescription.setText("");
                                edtLatitude.setText("");
                                edtLongitude.setText("");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure( Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(FirebaseTambah.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred() / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                        mProgressBar.setProgress((int) progress);
                    }
                });
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Tidak Ada File Yang Dipilih", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private void openImagesActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ImagesActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, ImageActivity1.class);
}
```

it is Upload.java

```
public Upload() {
    //empty constructor needed
}

public Upload(String name, String imageUrl, String description, String latitude, String longitude) {
    if (name.trim().equals("")) {
        name = "No Name";
    }

    mName = name;
    mImageUrl = imageUrl;
    mDescription = description;
    mLatitude = latitude;
    mLongitude = longitude;

}

public String getName() {
    return mName;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    mName = name;
}



public String getImageUrl() {
    return mImageUrl;
}

public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
    mImageUrl = imageUrl;
}
public void setDescription(String description){
    mDescription = description;
}
public String getDescription(){
    return mDescription;
}
public void setLatitude(String latitude){
    mLatitude = latitude;
}
public String getLatitude(){
    return mLatitude;
}
public void setLongitude(String longitude){
    mLongitude = longitude;
}
public String getLongitude(){
    return mLongitude;
}
@Exclude
public String getmKey(){
    return mKey;
}
@Exclude
public void setmKey(String key){
    mKey = key;
}
```

}

and this Maps.java

it is eror in   LatLng location = new LatLng(upload.getLatitude(),upload.getLongitude());
(this message " Latlng cannot be implement in String) i change in Upload.java with double in latitude and longitude,, and change in FirebaseTambah.java(to upload in firebase) with double.parsedouble..is done but cannot find setIcon in Maps.java  and still when klik get lokasi cannot display Map

https://github.com/YogieTryPambudi/YogieProject

```
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    ChildEventListener mChildEventListener;
    mUploads = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads");
    mUploads.push().setValue(marker);
}
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap){
    mMap = googleMap;
    googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
    mUploads.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot s : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Upload upload = s.getValue(Upload.class);
                LatLng location = new LatLng(upload.getLatitude(),upload.getLongitude());
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title(upload.getName().setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE))));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Comment: my datbase in firebase sir..     -Lf-MlbsPJLG3rnUmdOH
 description: 
"Dukuh Tinggen, Bentakan, Baki"
 imageUrl: 
"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/pen..."
 latitude: 
"110.782"
 longitude: 
"-7.61786"
 name: 
"PT. indosat.Tbk"

Comment: Please add to your question and not as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

try this

instead of `setIcon`

write

```
@Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot s : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            Upload upload = s.getValue(Upload.class);
            LatLng location = new LatLng(upload.getLatitude(),upload.getLongitude());
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title(upload.getName().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE))));
        }
    }
```

Comment: .icon still red underline sirr,, please help thanks

Comment: Marker myMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(currentPosition)
        .snippet("Lat:" + location.getLatitude() + "Lng" + location.getLongitude())
        .title("ME"));

myMarker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE))   Sir i change with code above is not eror in setIcon.. but marker does'nt view in my maps help,,